# Iterate through Nested, mixed dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have been using CrunchBase API, and the output provided is as the following example (actual example [here](http://ec2-107-21-104-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/v/1/company/stack-exchange.js)):

```
 output = {'name':'StackOverflow',
       'competitors':[{   'competitor':'bing',
                          'link':'bing.com'},
                      {   'competitor':'google',
                          'link':'google.com'}],
       'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                       'acquired_month': 12,
                       'acquired_year': 2013,
                       'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                             'permalink': 'viggle'}}}
```

(this is just an example).

The point is, in the output dict there are several values that can be unicode/int, lists or dictionaries. There values can hold lists, dict or unicode as well.

How could I iterate through the dict? I tried itertools.product but it only seems to work when the structure of the dict is uniform. My goal is to turn this output JSON file into a csv.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What fields do you actually want?  JSON doesn't translate cleanly to CSVs, since CSVs have to have a flat structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you wish to achieve exactly, but if your `output` is actually one line in the requested CSV, you may need to "flatten" the nested dictionary first.

Assuming your structure is a dict whose values are either "simple" (strings, floats, etc.), or dicts, or lists (nested, unlimited depth), and assume there's some character (for example, "_") which does not appear in any of the keys, you may flatten the dict using the following recursive function (or any other similar one):

```
def _flatten_items(items, sep, prefix):
  _items = []
  for key, value in items:
    _prefix = "{}{}".format(prefix, key)
    if isinstance(value, list):
      _items.extend(_flatten_items(list(enumerate(value)), sep=sep,
                    prefix=_prefix+sep))
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
      _items.extend(_flatten_items(value.items(), sep=sep,
                    prefix=_prefix+sep))
    else:
      _items.append((_prefix, value))
  return _items


def flatten_dict(d, sep='_'):
  return dict(_flatten_items(d.items(), sep=sep, prefix=""))
```

As an example, in your `output` this should give:

```
output = {'name':'StackOverflow',
       'competitors':[{   'competitor':'bing',
                          'link':'bing.com'},
                      {   'competitor':'google',
                          'link':'google.com'}],
       'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                       'acquired_month': 12,
                       'acquired_year': 2013,
                       'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                             'permalink': 'viggle'}}}

print flatten_dict(output)
# {'acquisition_acquired_year': 2013, 'acquisition_acquiring_company_name': 'Viggle', 'name': 'StackOverflow', 'acquisition_acquiring_company_permalink': 'viggle', 'competitors_0_competitor': 'bing', 'acquisition_acquired_month': 12, 'competitors_1_link': 'google.com', 'acquisition_acquired_day': 16, 'competitors_1_competitor': 'google', 'competitors_0_link': 'bing.com'}
```

Then you may use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) `DictWriter` (or similar) to write the output data to csv.

Comment: I love you Sir. I was close, but you nailed it.

Comment: That makes me glad; would you be kind enough to accept this answer?

Comment: Yes indeed. If i may ask. How would you do so instead of adding a prefix, you would replace the value of the existing key?

Comment: Without adding a prefix I take the risk of overriding an existing value. That means loss of data, and you probably don't want that. Of course, other means of assuring unique keys are available, such as having tuples as keys, etc.

Comment: hmm, what if i wanted to override? actually that might be good in case you are parsing a series of nested events and you just wanted the most recent one.

Comment: But a `dict` is not sorted, so you may get random results.

Comment: dammit you are right. Maybe i should use OrderedDict instead.